# Migrate a query from PLSQL TO SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I have this part of code written with PL/SQL

```
 if l_rec.sched_interval_type = 'DAYS' then    

      if l_max_date is null then     

        if l_rec.DAY_START_DAY is not null then     
           SELECT next_day(p_date, l_rec.DAY_START_DAY)    
           INTO l_start_date    
           FROM dual;    
        else    
           l_start_date := TRUNC(p_date);    
        end if;    

      else -- previous schedule recs exist...    

         if l_rec.DAY_START_DAY is not null then     
           SELECT next_day(GREATEST(l_max_date, p_date), l_rec.DAY_START_DAY)    
           INTO l_start_date    
           FROM dual;    
         else    
           l_start_date := l_max_date + l_rec.SCHED_AVAIL_DAYS;    
         end if;    

      end if;
```

I need to convert it into SQL SERVER

```
select 
CASE WHEN @l_max_date is null then    

    SELECT @l_start_date = CASE WHEN (SELECT sched_interval_type from #l_rec)  = 'DAYS' and @l_max_date is null and  @NextDayID is not null then    
    DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7),@p_date) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7))
          else CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, @p_date)) end 
          from #l_rec

     ELSE -- previous schedule recs exist...    

  SELECT @l_start_date = CASE WHEN (SELECT sched_interval_type from #l_rec)  = 'DAYS' and @l_max_date is null and  @NextDayID is not null then    
          DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7), [dbo].[greatest](@l_max_date, @p_date)) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7))
              else @l_max_date+ (SELECT SCHED_AVAIL_DAYS from #l_rec) end 
              from #l_rec
         END
```

I have problems with `case.. when`. Is there a way to modify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT @l_start_date = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @l_max_date is null THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN sched_interval_type = 'DAYS' AND @l_max_date IS NULL AND @NextDayID IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7),@p_date) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7))
                    ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, @p_date)) 
                END
            ELSE
                CASE 
                    WHEN sched_interval_type = 'DAYS' AND @l_max_date IS NULL AND @NextDayID IS NOT NULL THEN DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7), [dbo].[greatest](@l_max_date, @p_date)) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7))
                    ELSE @l_max_date+ SCHED_AVAIL_DAYS
                END
         END 
FROM #l_rec
```

Comment: What is the benefit of having one `CASE` that checks `@l_max_date is null` and then multiple inner `CASE` expressions that each check `@l_max_date IS NULL`? Is null/NULL case sensitive? Will `@l_max_date` ever be NULL for the second inner `CASE` if the outer `CASE` already determined that it isn't?

Comment: No. You're quite correct. The logic in the above statement need refactoring. I blindly converted the given MySQL to MS SQL, and didn't pay attention to what the query actually does. P.s. NULL == null

Comment: @Spock How can I modify it ?I didn't understand .

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL a `CASE` *expression* returns a single value of some type. (There is no `CASE` statement.) You can use something like:

```
set @L_Start_Date = case
  when @L_Max_Date is null then
    ( select ... )
  when <some other condition> then
    ( some other expression that results in a single value )
  else
    ( expression that provides a default value )
  end
```

Note that the assignment of a value to the variable is not performed in the `SELECT`, it simply returns a value to the `CASE`.